# Check if the circle is inside the Rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles, rectangles

As shown in the following figures, the upper right coordinate (W,H) of the rectangle and the central coordinate (x, y) and radius r of the circle are given. So how can I determines whether the circle is arranged inside the rectangle.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The circle is within the rectangle as long as its center lies on a rectangle that has a distance of r to the outer/original rectangle. So, as long as the coordinates of the circle's center fulfill the following boundary conditions, your circle lies within the rectangle.

$$
r \le x \le W-r\\
r \le y \le H-r
$$

In the third figure, you see that the ordinate $y = H$ does not satisfy $y \le H-r$, although $x$ satisfies its boundary condition. So *both* conditions apply.